# Prove that a specific analytic function has $n^{th}$ derivative identically zero for sufficiently large $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on this question:

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function such that $$(1+|z|^{k})\dfrac{d^{m}f}{dz^{m}}$$ is bounded for some $k$ and $m$. Prove that $$\dfrac{d^{n}f}{dz^{n}}\ \text{is identically zero}$$ for sufficiently large $n$. How large must $n$ be in terms of $k$ and $m$?

**Here is what I've attempted but I was stuck in the end.**

Bounded entire function is constant, so $$(1+|z|^{k})\dfrac{d^{m}f}{dz^{m}}=C,$$ which gives us $$f^{(m)}(z)=\dfrac{C}{1+|z|^{k}},\ \text{for some}\ C.$$

Set $g(z):=f^{(m)}(z)$, which is also entire.

Thus, for all $z_{0}\in\mathbb{C}$, we can always find an open set that $g$ is holomorphic in and contains the closure of a disc $D(z_{0}, R)$, for $R$ large enough, such that, by Cauchy's inequalities, we have $$|g^{(\ell)}(z_{0})|=|f^{(m+\ell)}(z_{0})|\leq\dfrac{\ell!\sup_{z\in \partial D}|g(z)|}{R^{\ell}},\ \text{for all}\ \ell\geq 0.$$

Now, for $z\in\partial D$, we have 
\begin{align*}
|g(z)|&=\dfrac{|C|}{1+|z|^{k}}\\
&=\dfrac{|C|}{1+R^{k}}\\
&\leq\dfrac{|C|}{|R^{k}-1|}.
\end{align*}

Thus, 
\begin{align*}
\sup_{z\in\partial D}|g(z)|&=\dfrac{|C|}{|R^{k}-1|}\\
&=\dfrac{|C|}{R^{k}-1},\ \text{for}\ R\ \text{large enough}.
\end{align*}

This gives us $$|g^{(\ell)}(z_{0})|=|f^{(m+\ell)}(z)|\leq |C|\ell!\dfrac{1}{R^{\ell}(R^{k}-1)}.$$

Taking $R\longrightarrow\infty$, we have $$|g^{(\ell)}(z_{0})|\leq 0.$$

Thus, for all $z_{0}\in\mathbb{C}$, we have $$|g^{(\ell)}(z_{0})|=|f^{(m+\ell)}(z_{0})|=0,\ $$

Here is what I am stuck in. It seems that $n$ does not really depend on $k$, since $f^{(m+\ell)}\equiv 0$ for al $\ell\geq 0$.

I think there must be something wrong in my argument.

Please feel free to give any corrections or hints!

Thank you!

**As what Martin R mentioned, there is a similar question here:** [Let $f$ be entire such that $(1+|z|^k)^{-1}\frac{d^m f}{dz^m}$ is bounded for some $k, m$. Prove $d^nf/dz^n$ is $0$ for some $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907951/let-f-be-entire-such-that-1zk-1-fracdm-fdzm-is-bounded-for-so/3285266#3285266). Except in that question, it is $(1+|z|^{k})^{-1}\dfrac{d^{m}f}{dz^{m}}$ that is bounded. I attache this related question here for people to have more similar and interesting reference.

Comment: The beginning is a bit loose. Bounded doesn't mean it equals a constant, it means the magnitude is less than or equal to some constant for all $z$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  so it is a bounded entire function, and Liouville's Theorem states that bounded entire function is constant.

Comment: Why is $(1+|z|^k)f^{(m)}(z)$ entire?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt As $f$ is holomorphic in the whole complex plane, as stated in the question, and $1+|z|^{k}$ has no pole.

Comment: Should it perhaps be $(1+|z|^k)^{-1}\frac{d^m f}{dz^m}$, as in this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1907951/42969?

Comment: @MartinR I really wish... but I just checked the question, it has no $-1$. Is that possible to prove this question if it is not $-1$?

Comment: Is $k \ge 0$? Then $(1+|z|^{k})\dfrac{d^{m}f}{dz^{m}}$ bounded implies that $\dfrac{d^{m}f}{dz^{m}}$ is bounded, and thus constant (and actually zero, if $k >0$).

Comment: $1+|z|^k$ isn't even analytic, so there's no reason for $(1+|z|^k)f^{(m)}(z)$ to be analytic, unless $f^{(m)}(z)=0$. And I think it should follow quite easily from what Martin said

Comment: @MartinR No, there is no information about $k$, but I agree with your argument for $k\geq 0$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yes I think you are right.. I am just proving something I assumed at the very beginning.

Comment: $|(1+|z|^k)f^{(m)}(z)| \le M$ implies $|f^{(m)}(z)| \le \frac{M}{1+|z|^k} \le M$.

Comment: @MartinR yes you are right. but I think this also holds for $k<0$? since $1+|z|^{k}\geq1$ for all $k$?

Comment: Yes, it does....

Comment: @MartinR so as long as $n\geq m+1$, $f^{n}$ would always be 0....??

Comment: @MartinR I got your point. Sorry for my confusion. So if $k>0$ and $k<0$, then $n=m$ can work. If $k=0$, then $n\geq m+1$. That's why $n$ is in terms of $k$.

Comment: @MartinR Do you want to post an answer so that I can upvote+accept? or I will post the answer myself. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|(1+|z|^k)f^{(m)}(z)| \le M$ then
$$ \tag{*}
|f^{(m)}(z)| \le \frac{M}{1+|z|^k} \le M \, ,
$$
so that (Liouville!) $f^{(m)}(z)$ is constant, and therefore $f^{(n)} = 0$ for $n \ge m+1$.

If $k \ne 0$ then $(*)$ implies even  $f^{(m)} = 0$.

Comment: I think $(*)$ also imply $f^{(m)}=0$ if $k<0$. (We can take $z\rightarrow 0$.)